# How to load class from .apk at run time in API 19?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to load jar files at run time. It seems to work perfectly on an Android device with API lvl 23 (Android 6.0) but on API lvl 19 (Android 4.4.2) it always throws the following exception:

```
Process: ..., PID: 16144
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{path.to.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "path.to.MyClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/path.to.my.ap/files/MyApk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "path.to.MyClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/path.to.my.ap/files/MyApk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at ....
    at ....
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:38)
    at ....
```

So I'm loading jar files through **PathClassLoder** at runtime like this:

```
    val classLoader = PathClassLoader(file.absolutePath, applicationContext.classLoader)
    val class = classLoader.loadClass("path.to.MyClass").kotlin
    return class.constructors.first().call(params...) as MyClass
```

Would really appreciate some help here!

Edit:
The grade file for the apk's looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':core')
}
```

Edit 2:
I also notices another exception occurring right before the other one:

```
E/dalvikvm: Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache (Permission denied) uid=10037 gid=10037
```

Could this be the source of the problem why is it not writeable on api 19 but on api 23 it is? 
Is there something i can do about it?

Comment: How was your JAR file built? It complains about it not having a DEX.

Comment: add multidex support to your application

Comment: @shkschneider Added the gradle build file to the question, i also looked into the apk with Analize apk (Android Studio) and i can see the dex file and the class in there. Also it works on API 23 this is so strange annoying :/

Comment: @VivekMishra The application already has Multidex support

Comment: I can't see any code related to multidex in your gradle file

Comment: @VivekMishra this is the gradle file of the apk i try to import not the application gradle file. Or do you mean i should add Multidex support there as well?